# Как перевести unsigned int в 4 байта char, есть ли встроенные функции в c++

Tags: c++

имеется hash-функция, которая возвращает unsigned int, его нужно записать в 4 байта unsigned char, как это сделать?

Comment: Обычно используют наложение маски и сдвиг. А вот про встроенные функции не слышал.

Comment: `````memcpy`````

Comment: `reinterpret_cast`

Comment: ох блин, вот не надо этого советовать, @Chorkov

Comment: @Arenoros почему? Выравнивание char не выше unsigned int. Это обратно нельзя.

Comment: @Chorkov, потому что UB и это плохая практика, есть memcpy и в таких случаях всегда лучше использовать его. Он максимально оптимизирован для таких вот вызовов и даже на O0 не будет сгенерирован вызов реальной функции

Comment: @Arenoros, вообще-то в указатель на char разрешено кастить.

Comment: @Qwertiy В с++ вообще очень много чего разрешено), но это не значит что стоит так делать, особенно людям которые задают подобные вопросы

Comment: @Arenoros, вы всерьез думаете, что реализации memcpy построены на особой магии?

Comment: Проще всего, если устраивает родной (native) порядок байт -- `unsigned char *p = (__typeof__(p))&your_4_bytes_var;` Далее можете обращаться `p[0]`, `p[2]` и т.п.

Comment: @avp, Магия тут не причём, это просто рекомендуемый способ каста подобных вещей, вам действительно нужно объяснять что такое **best practice**? А по поводу вашего следующего комментария, это ....,в общем желаю вам в будущем почаще ревьювить подобный г..код...

Comment: @Arenoros, по поводу **best practice** и кочества сорсов, тут похоже, сколько программеров, столько и мнений  (м.б. кроме KISS) -)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Предполагая, что b[0] LSB:

```
unsigned int n = get_value();
unsigned char b[4];

b[0] = static_cast<unsigned char>(n & 0xFF);
b[1] = static_cast<unsigned char>((n>>8) & 0xFF);
b[2] = static_cast<unsigned char>((n>>16) & 0xFF);
b[3] = static_cast<unsigned char>((n>>24) & 0xFF);
```

Нужен обратный порядок - поменяйте индексы.

Если порядок совпадает с Endianness, можно использовать `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(b,&n, sizeof(b));
```

Для числа `0x11223344` `memcpy` на компьютере Little Endian даст `44 33 22 11`, на компьютере Big Endian даст `11 22 33 44`. 
Если нужен порядок Big Endian, можете использовать `ntohl` - сработает на любом компьютере.

```
unsigned int n = get_value();
unsigned int n1 = htonl(n);    // n1 is in network byte order, Big Endian
memcpy(b, &n1, sizeof(b));
```

Comment: если не совпадает есть `htonl(uint32_t hostlong)`, так что первый вариант я бы лучше совсем убрал, а то потом на код ревью запаришся вычищать это

Comment: @AlexF, а зачем тут вообще обилие букв для приведения типа (неужели вам платят посимвольно)? Достаточно `b[0] = n; b[1] = n >> 8; b[2] = n >> 16; b[3] = n >> 24;` (типы же ведь все подходят)

Comment: @AlexF,  `gcc/g++ -Wpedantic -Wextra -std=...` не ругаются

Answer (score -1):

Можно используя union. Нужно только учесть порядок байтов.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    union Data {
        unsigned int i_data;
        unsigned char c_data[4];
    };

    Data data1;
    data1.i_data = 0x41424344;

    for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) 
        std::cout << data1.c_data[i];
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: В union нужно обязательно делать volatile члены. Иначе компилятор выдерет все присвоения в i_data. Для оптимизации. Попробуйте для практики включить оптимизацию.